# format for citing treaties in bibtex

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I have a question on citation styles in bibtex. I want to cite the Maastricht Treaty; since it seems there is no specific citation style for treaties, I came up with the following approximation:

```
@book{
maastricht,
    author= "European Union",
    title=     "Treaty on European Union",
    publisher=     "OJ C 191, 29.7.1992, pp. 1-112",
    year=      "7 February 1992",
    note= {https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A11992M%2FTXT [latest access: 18/08/21]}
}
```

but in the bibliography it is cited as:
Union, E. (7 February 1992). Treaty on European Union. OJ C 191, 29.7.1992, pp. 1-112. [https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legalcontent/EN/TXT/?uri=celex[latest](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legalcontent/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%5Blatest) access: 18/08/21].

which is not the correct way to reference a treaty.
I'm afraid this question may be off-topic, but I really can't find a proper way to cite treaties in bibtex.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I saw a post on a similar topic, but I was unable to apply their suggestion to my case

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Are you just concerned about the author field? If so just enclose the European Union in a set of {…}.

Comment: In part I am, thank you very much for the suggestion. However, I was hoping to get a citation like the following: Treaty of Lisbon amending the Treaty on European Union and the Treaty establishing the European Community, 13 December 2007. [Online]. 2007/C 306/01. [Accessed 13 May 2017]. Available from: http://eur-lex.europa.eu/

Comment: You need to give us more information on the bibliography style and package you are using. And add the expected format to the question since not everyone will read the comments.

Comment: `Biblatex` has the (nonstandard) `legal` type, described as ‘Legal documents such as treaties’.

Comment: Sorry, I am using the natbib package for citations